Field isomorphism between copies of $\mathbb R$
$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\tld}{\tilde}
\newcommand{\tldt}{\mathbin{\tilde{\cdot}}}
$
Resource: Mathematical Analysis: A Concise Introduction, by Schröder
Exercise: 1-30 (b) v. (p. 16). I paste the entire exercise at the bottom of this question.
Background:  We take axiomatically $\R$ as a complete, ordered field. We want to show that given another structure $\tld{\R}$ that is also a complete, ordered field, there is an isomorphism $f \colon \R \to \tld{\R}$ between them. We have defined $f(x) := \sup\left\{ f(r) \colon r \in \Q \text{ and } r \leq x \right\}$. We use $\tilde{}$ notation when referring to anything to do with $\tld{\R}$.
Objective: We want to show that $f(x \cdot y) = f(x) \tldt f(y)$ for $x < 0$ and $y > 0$. I think I have dealt with all the other cases.
My attempt: By definition of $f$, given $x < 0$ and $y > 0$ we want to show that
\begin{align*}
\sup\left\{ f(r) \colon r \in \Q \text{ and } r \leq xy \right\} = \sup\left\{ f(p) \colon p \in \Q \text{ and } p \leq x \right\} \tldt \sup\left\{ f(q) \colon q \in \Q \text{ and } q \leq y \right\}. \qquad (1)
\end{align*}
Our strategy is to show that the RHS of (1) is the supremum of the set on the LHS of (1), so we need to show that the RHS is an upper bound for the LHS, and then that it is the least upper bound. In particular, I have been trying to somehow "reduce" this case to the case when $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, which I already have a proof for, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Copy of Exercise:

